# Method to deserialize gson string with generic type wont work with arrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, generics, gson

I wrote a utility function to help convert firebase data objects into java objects using gson since their built in jackson converter is terrible.
The method works fine for Objects, but not for an ArrayList of objects

```
 public class FirebaseUtil {

    public static <T extends Object> T getValue(Object value, Class<T> valueType) {

        String stringValue = new Gson().toJson(value);
        return new Gson().fromJson(stringValue, valueType);
    }
 }
```

Then I can do somethign like

```
 Card card = FirebaseUtil.getValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), Card.class)
```

But if I want to deserialize an array of objects it wont work

```
  Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Card>>() {}.getType();

  ArrayList<Card> cards = FirebaseUtil.getValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(),listType);
```

I think I might need a second helper method but not sure what the second paramater should be

EDIT:
this method seems to work

```
public static <T> T getValue(Object value, Type type) {

    String stringValue = new Gson().toJson(value);
    return new Gson().fromJson(stringValue, type);
}
```

Comment: Define _it wont work_. Also, you used `Card` in one place and `Trip` in the other. Your method seems to expect a `Class`, you're passing it a `Type`.

Comment: yeah the Trip object was a typo